# Raise ParentChanged event programmatically of a Control

Tags: c#, winforms, events, controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find row index of control added to TableLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800520/find-row-index-of-control-added-to-tablelayoutpanel)

Can we raise `ParentChanged` event programmatically in Windows Forms for a control?

Or for that matter raise any event of a control programmatically?

Comment: Found answer at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293007/is-it-possible-to-steal-an-event-handler-from-one-control-and-give-it-to-anoth

see post from Hans Passant

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is not possible from an outside caller.

In a Control-derived class, you can call:

```
base.OnParentChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
```